# Default value for a port?

Tags: noflo

Is it possible to set a default value or an IIP (Initial Information Packet) for a port via Coffee/Javascript?

Often it would be nice to set a default value for a port so that there's some initial data to start with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is a new feature that will ship in NoFlo 0.5. Using the [new Port API](https://github.com/noflo/noflo/issues/136), `noflo.InPort` instances will send the value received via the `default` port options key when started.

So, something like:

```
noflo = require 'noflo'
exports.getComponent = ->
  new noflo.Component
    inPorts:
      foo:
        datatype: 'string'
        default: 'baz'
```